# How to integrate Whatsapp with Power virtual agent without using Azure service?

Tags: node.js, power-automate, azure-bot-service, power-automate-custom-connector, power-virtual-agents

When I tried creating a WhatsApp channel through Microsoft power virtual agent,
they have provided BotID and Tenant ID and a [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-virtual-agents/publication-connect-bot-to-azure-bot-service-channels)
which is redirecting to the azure bot service.
Is there any way to use Power Virtual Agent or Power Automate w/o using Azure bot service?

If we have to use a bot service is the only way to use NodeJS as in the Doc and Github code in C#.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Power virtual agents don't provide a way to natively integrate with WhatsApp and you need to follow the steps mentioned in the documentation.

You should be able to use the language of your choice for which BotFramework has an SDK: https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk